# How to handle the situation where (possibly mutually exclusive) optional subjects are alloted to each student?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have created the following ERD:
[image: Entity Relationship Diagram]

Each student is under one department.

Each department has fixed number of semesters.(semester is not a table, as of now.)

Each semester has many subjects.(One subject may exist in more than 1 dept. This is currently **not** depicted in the diagram.)

Some subjects are compulsory, some are *optional* (or *elective*).(decided by `isCompulsory` boolean.)

There is a restriction on the optional subject allotment.  <s>Say, there are 3 optional subjects OptSubA, OptSubB, OptSubC in dept X in sem Z. Now, it may happen that a student can choose only 1 of them. It may also happen that the student can choose any 2 of them.</s> Striked out as this example was highly ambiguous. What I want to say is that the rule is not pre-decided but the Admin should be able to add the rule.

*Edit:* The rule is something like this

> Every Student of a Sem X of Dept Y has to choose exactly 1 subject out of given M optional subjects AND 1 subject out of Q other optional subjects and so on. (i.e., optional subjects are grouped together). *Every student must choose exactly 1 Subject out of each group.*

I will be happy if I am able to design even this highly simplified rule (though above rule is my ultimate goal) :

> Every Student of a Sem X of Dept Y has to choose N subjects out of given M optional subjects.

Edit 2 : Example :  Consider, Sem Y of DEPT X. The optional subject in a group has similar codes. E.g., `PE 501 A` , `PE 501 B`. There may be yet another group having Subject codes like `PE 502 A`, `PE 502 B`, `PE 503 C`, `PE 503 D`. The student needs to choose 1 Subject from first group and 1 Subject from second group. The number of such groups is not known beforehand. Admin should be able to add/remove/modify the groups.

I have created a table `student_optional_subject` which stores `student_id` and `subject_code`. This table is capable of storing which subjects are chosen by the student but I cannot understand *how to store the rule and impose the same*.

Any ideas?

Besides, this is my first question on this site, so please tell me if I have posted the question in wrong subdomain.

Sorry for editing it so many times. First time asking a DB Related Question.

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea is to add a relation, say student_optimal_no:

```
CREATE TABLE student_optional_no
( student_id ... not null references student (id)
, optional_no int not null
,     primary key (student_id, optional_subject_no)
);
```

If student X can have 4 optional subjects, 4 rows are inserted:

```
insert into student_optional_no (student_id, optional_no)
values (X,1),(X,2),(X,3),(X,4);
```

Then add this attribute to student_optional_subject, and make a foreign key to student_optional_no. When adding a student_optional_subject, pick the smallest available number for the student in student_optional_no.

EDIT:

Given the clarifications I would suggest something like:

```
CREATE TABLE number_of_student_subjects
( student_id ... not null references student (id)
, type_of_rule char(1) not null  -- M=Mandatory, O=Optional
, number_of_subjects int default 0 not null
,     primary key (student_id, type_of_rule)
);
```

Example

```
insert into number_of_student_subjects
    (student_id, type_of_rule, number_of_subjects)
values (X, 'M', 3)
     , (X, 'O', 2);
```

If the set of Mandatory/Optional subjects for each student has to be defined

```
CREATE TABLE student_subject_collection
( student_id ... not null references student (id)
, subject_id ... not null references subject (id)
, type_of_rule char(1) not null  -- M=Mandatory, O=Optional
,     primary key (student_id, subject_id, type_of_rule)
);
```

What the student enrols in:

```
CREATE TABLE student_subject_enrolement
( student_id ... not null references student (id)
, subject_id ... not null references subject (id)
,     primary key (student_id, subject_id)
);
```

The results

```
CREATE TABLE student_subject_result
( student_id ... not null 
, subject_id ... not null 
,     foreign key (student_id, subject_id)
          references student_subject_enrolement (student_id, subject_id) 
, ...
,     primary key (student_id, subject_id)
);
```

To verify whether a student has the correct number of enrolments you can compare the number of enrolments with the number of mandatory and so forth.

Sorry, I'm in a hurry so that's the best I can do at the moment.

Comment: My rule was quite ambiguous. I have added a bit of clarification in the question. Can you please take a look and update your answer to reflect the same? Every student gets the same number of subjects to choose.

Comment: A rule like: `Every Student of a Sem X of Dept Y has to choose N subjects out of given M optional subjects.` can not be enforced in the case that a student chooses only N-1 subjects. If they must choose all subjects at once, a transaction with all or nothing semantics can be implemented. But in any case. a violation can, of course, be detected and acted upon. I'll see if I get the time during today to come up with something.

Comment: I am ok with forcing students to choose it at once. Sorry, I have again edited the Question to make it more clear and concise. I hope I am not creating trouble.